# How do I create an html form with multiple checkboxes

Tags: php, html, forms

This is my code for creating an html form that reads from a database and will allow the user to check and uncheck boxes for each of the 640 items.  This is the form.php:

```php
// execute query 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query. ".mysql_error());

// see if any rows were returned 
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) { 
    // yes 
    // print them one after another 
    echo "<html><body>  <table cellpadding=10 border=1>"; 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
        echo "<tr>"; 
        echo "<td>".$row['stickerID']."</td>"; 
        echo "<td>" .$row['stickerName']."</td>"; 
        echo "<td>".$row['stickerSection']."</td>"; 
        echo "<td>"?>
                 <form name="some form" action="editform.php" method="post">
                 <input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $row['stickerID'] ?>" value=" <?php echo $row['stickerStatus'] ?> ">
                 <?php "</td>";
        echo "</tr>"; 
    }
    echo "</table></body></html>";
    echo " " ?>
                 <input type="submit" name="editWish" value="Edit">
                 </form>
                 <?php " ";
} else { 
    // no 
    // print status message 
    echo "No rows found!"; 
}
```

The user must then be able to click on submit and have those values updated in the mysql database.

Right now when I click the submit button, it posts to edit form.php which has this:

```php
<?php

//echo results
foreach($_POST['stickerID'] as $k=>$v ){
echo $k;
echo $v;
}

?>
```

But I don't get anything echoed.  I was thinking the problem could be that Im actually creating a form for every row instead of 1 form with many rows/checkboxes.  But when I move the form code after the   and the  tag to the line where  line, I can't even load the form.php, it just loads blank.

Where is my problem? :)  Thx

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: Thanks Amal, could you help me with that?  Right now I just need to get this working even with a quick and dirty fix.  Then I could spend more time studying how to upgrade it.

Comment: add [] to your checkbox name, for example name="myCheckbox[]".
This will allow you to submit everything as array and your loop will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name your checkbox like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="stickerID[]" value=" <?php echo $row['stickerStatus']; ?> ">
```

And as Amal already said update your code to PDO or MySQLi

Comment: Thanks.  Now Im getting key=>value for only the items check marked in the form.  However, since all values in the database are initially zero, I need to now get the value from the actual post for those selected items.  meaning that if I select items 1, 2 & 3, I get 1=>0, 2=>0 & 3=>0.  But I would actually want to update those to 1, not 0.  How would I do that?

Comment: in the value from your checkbox give it the value `$row['stickerID'];` Than in your `foreach` update your table `WHERE stickerID` = `$value` and set value to 1.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with a tag :-

```
echo "<td>" .$row['stickerName']."</td>"; 
        echo "<td>".$row['stickerSection']."</td>"; 
        echo "<td>"?>


                 <form name="some form" action="editform.php" method="post">
                 <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value=" <?php echo $row['stickerStatus'] ?> ">
                 <?php "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
```

on your php code you get :-

```
$all_checkes_checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];
```

here is your all checked checkbox:-
and this array also bale key and value